# FunctionInterpolation error when specifying AccuracyGoal

Tags: bugs, interpolation

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

In the help page [`ref/message/FunctionInterpolation/ncvb`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/FunctionInterpolation/ncvb.html), it is mentioned that one should specify `AccuracyGoal` for some (even very simple) functions:

```
FunctionInterpolation[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 2]
```

However, when I evaluate it, a lot of error messages are generated, such as

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {-(1/8),-(1/24),1/24,1/8}^{} cannot be combined.
>      FunctionInterpolation::nreal: "Near x = 1/8, the function did not evaluate to a real number.

Also, the precision I got is very bad (as one can check using `Plot[%[x] - Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`). The error is about 5% so not usable for realistic work (and the situation does not change when I increase AccuracyGoal).

Is it a bug? Perhaps I have to do `Interpolation` or `ListInterpolation` by hand myself.

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 7, 2013)"

PS: I found this thread may be related but still different [FunctionInterpolation Errors / Question re Evaluation Order and Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/functioninterpolation-errors-question-re-evaluation-order-and-options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to real numbers:

```
fi = FunctionInterpolation[Sqrt[x], {x, 0., 1.}]

Plot[fi@x, {x, 0., 1.}]
```

[image]

The "error" is very small:

```
Plot[fi@x - Sqrt@x, {x, 0., 1.}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's a nice workaround. But considering the integer argument appears in Mathematica's official documentation (also the error messages are not relevant), perhaps I should mark this question as a bug?

Comment: @YiWang - Using `{0, 1}` causes a relatively large pertubation near `0`, wheras `0.` behaves much better near `0`. Yes, maybe it's a bug since `Sqrt[0] == 0` and not something near `0`.