# FunctionInterpolation produces many error messages when given high-precision input

Tags: bugs, interpolation, precision-and-accuracy

Both

```
FunctionInterpolation[1, {x, 0,1.00000000000000004}]
```

and

```
FunctionInterpolation[1.00000000000000004, {x, 0, 1}];
```

give mysterious errors:

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {-0.12500000000000000,-0.04166666666666667,
>       0.04166666666666667,0.12500000000000000}^{} cannot be combined. >>
>   Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {-2.0794415416798359+3.1415926535897932 I,
>       -3.1780538303479456+3.1415926535897932 I,-<<58>>,-2.0794415416798359} {} cannot be combined. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of Thread::tdlen will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>   FunctionInterpolation::nreal: Near x = 0.125`17., the function did not evaluate to a real number. >>

Here `1.00000000000000004` has precision 17, which is larger than `MachinePrecision` ~ 15.  Removing a couple of zeros avoids the errors.  Manually lowering the precision also works, as this gives no errors:

```
FunctionInterpolation[1, {x, 0, SetPrecision[1.00000000000000004, MachinePrecision]}]
```

Increasing `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` do nothing, and the option `WorkingPrecision` is not used.

Finally, note that other functions like `Plot[]` don't have this problem:

```
Plot[1, {x, 0,1.00000000000000004}]
```

works fine.

I'm on 10.3.0.0 on OSX.  What's going on?

Please note that I need high-precision output, so ignoring the errors isn't sufficient, nor are the older questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4255/functioninterpolation-errors-question-re-evaluation-order-and-options) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51224/functioninterpolation-error-when-specifying-accuracygoal).  The behavior of this error makes it difficult to isolate, but here is an example where a fix is needed:

```
With[{n = 1.001}, Block[{f, A1, B1},
  f = Function[{A}, ArcSin[n* Sin[A]] - A];
  A1 = ArcSin[1/n];
  B1 = f[A1];
  g = FunctionInterpolation[Sin[InverseFunction[f][B]], {B, 0, B1}, MaxRecursion -> 12];
  Plot[g[B], {B, 0, B1}, PlotRange -> Full]
]]
```

which plots this as expected:

[image]

But if we replace `n = 1.001` with `1.00000000000000004`, which pushes the curve further toward the upper left-hand corner, we get errors which depend on the value of `MaxRecursion` and other details, or the computation my simply become intractably slow.

Comment: It's actually useful for me to give `FunctionInterpolation[]` high-precision data, since I need to approximate the function right up to the (high-precision) point that it becomes undefined.

Comment: Use exact numbers, e.g., `FunctionInterpolation[1, Evaluate@{x, 0, 1.00000000000000004 // Rationalize[#, 0] &}]` and `FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate@Rationalize[1.00000000000000004, 0], {x, 0, 1}]`  Although there are no errors without the use of `Evaluate`, I include its use since `FunctionInterpolation` has attribute `HoldAll`

Comment: Will `FunctionInterpolation` use high-precision internally, or this equivalent to using `SetPrecision[1.00000000000000004,MachinePrecision]`?  What's going on with this anyways?

Comment: `f = FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate@Rationalize[1.00000000000000004, 0], {x, 0, 1}];`  Even with an exact input the result has machine precision, e.g., `f[1/2] // Precision` evaluates to `MachinePrecision`

Comment: OK, so then that doesn't really help, right?

Comment: Related?: [(51224)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51224/121)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I saw that question, but the solutions ("just make the input numerical" or "just ignore the errors") don't help solve my actual problem.  I will try to build a minimal working example to illustrate this.  At the minimum, I'd want to outputed `InterpolatedFunction` to have more than machine precision.

Comment: FWIW, this sort of problem has led me to avoid FunctionInterpolation (even when I shouldn't). I sometimes use NDSolve to construct an interpolation, either from an ODE or a DAE.

Answer (score 4):

This is an irritating bug that was introduced in V8 and has not been fixed even in the latest version (10.4.1) of *Mathematica*.

Both

```
f = FunctionInterpolation[N[1, 20] x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
g = FunctionInterpolation[N[1, 2] x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

give a spate of error messages similar to ones you encountered. In both cases the functions returned appear to behave normally. For example, both `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]` and `Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}]` produce a plot that looks like

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Unfortunately this isn't sufficient, as I've edited my question to try and explain.